# API-Platform - updating nullable string error

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have an entity which is exposed as an api-platform resource, and contains the following property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $note;
```

When I try to update the entity (via PUT), sending the following json:

```
{
  "note": null
}
```

I get the following error from the Symfony Serializer:

> [2017-06-29 21:47:33] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: "Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given" at /var/www/html/testapp/server/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php line 196 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException(code: 0):Expected argument of type \"string\", \"NULL\" given at /var/www/html/testapp/server/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php:196, Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Expected argument of type \"string\", \"NULL\" given at /var/www/html/testapp/server/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php:275)"} []

It seems like I'm missing some config to allow nulls on this property? To make things weirder, when I GET a resource containing a null note, then the note is correctly returned as null:

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/RentPayment",
  "@id": "/rent_payments/1",
  "@type": "RentPayment",
  "id": 1,
  "note": null,
  "date": "2016-03-01T00:00:00+00:00"
}
```

What am I missing - ps I'm a massive newb to api-platform

Comment: Just a wild stab but are you using a type hinted setter?

Comment: Thank you! Ugh, why didn't I think of that - add it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright then as determined in the comments you were using a type hinted setter à la:

```
public function setNote(string $note) {
    $this->note = $note;
    return $this;
}
```

As of PHP 7.1 we have [nullable types](http://php.net/manual/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types) so the following would be preferred as it actually checks null or string instead of any type.

```
public function setNote(?string $note = null) {
```

In previous versions just remove the type hint and if preferred add some type checking inside.

```
public function setNote($note) {
    if ((null !== $note) && !is_string($note)) {
        // throw some type exception!
    }
    
    $this->note = $note;
    return $this;
}
```

Another thing you might want to consider is using something like:

```
$this->note = $note ?: null;
```

This is the sorthand if ([ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)). To set the value to null if the string is empty (but bugs on '0' so you might need to do the longer version).